# Seemingly missing keyboard shortcuts; Can I create them myself?

Tags: unity, gnome, 12.04, shortcut-keys

I've noticed that Ctrl+Alt+Numpad moves a window around to fill bits of the screen, but it seems to be missing three shortcuts: Ctrl+Alt+Num4 to fill the left, Ctrl+Alt+Num6 to fill the right, and some sort of keyboard shortcut to move a window from one monitor to the other (like Super+Shift+Right or Super+Shift+Left in Windows 7). Can I somehow make these three keyboard shortcuts work?

Edit: Found out Ctrl+Super+Left and Ctrl+Super+Right to fill the left and right halves of the screen, but still no way to move a window between monitors.

Comment: Are you using Unity or Unity-2D? I think these are part of the Unity compiz plugin and not available for 2D.

Comment: I don't know, I'm just using Ubuntu.

Comment: Can you drag windows to the left or right edge and have them fill half the screen? if so, you're using Unity 3D and we can make some shortcuts for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the compiz config settings tool. You can install it with

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager
```

By typing that command in a terminal. You can then launch the application in unity; just start typing the word comiz and you'll see it.

There's lots of fun options to play around with in here. The one that you probably want to look at is the grid tool. Just remember if you manage to damage something and cause unity to stop working, typing

```
unity --reset
```

In a terminal and this will reset the profile to default and revert your changes.

Comment: Awesome! I ran that, and looked around. I found it under "Put," which I had to enable. The option was called "Put To Next Output," which unfortunately is a toggle. Do you know if it's possible to have two different shortcuts do the same function? (Since I only have two displays, it wouldn't matter if I hit Super+Shift+Left or Super+Shift+Right, but as it stands I can only seem to enable one of them.)

Comment: Hmm, possibly, but I don't think you can use ccsm for that. You can manually edit the values in using gconf-editor and looking under apps->compiz->plugins. Perhaps and "or" may be accepted in the keybinding sting, eg "<Super><Alt> | <Shift><Alt>" but I think it's unlikely. You're best best is probably to look for something that will let you remap keyboard keys. xmodmap comes to mind.

Comment: Hmm, the "or" pipe didn't work, so I've just set the key combination for Put To Next Output to `<Shift><Control><Primary><Alt>KP_Delete` instead. Thanks a bunch! Marking as answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can change or add keyboard shortcut with the System Settings with the Keyboard function, Shortcuts tab.

Comment: There's nothing in there about moving windows between monitors. There's "Window one workspace to the [left/right]", but that's not monitors, it's spaces.